# Python : Convert svg to png without antialiasing

Tags: python, svg, inkscape

I'm triying to convert a svg to png in python, but I don't want any compression and antialiasing.
I've tried to use inkscape with subprocess but i can't find the arguments to tell inkscape that i don't want any compression and antialisazing.

```
inkscape_path = "D:/Programmes/bin/inkscape.exe"
dpi_value = 300

result = subprocess.run([inkscape_path, "cleaned.svg", "--export-id=layer1", "--export-ignore-filters", "--export-type=png", "--export-filename=" + "cleaned.png", "--export-dpi=" + str(dpi_value)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

if result.returncode != 0:
    print("Error: " + result.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
else:
    print("PNG file exported successfully.")
```

I've also tried to do it with wand, but there is still antialiasing despite img.antialisaing = False :

```
# Load SVG file as an image object
with Image(filename='cleaned.svg') as img:
    # Disable antialiasing
    library.MagickSetOption(img.wand, b'antialias', b'0')
    img.antialias = False
    
    # Convert image format to PNG
    img.format = 'png'
    
    # Save without compression
    img.compression_quality = 100

    # Save to 300 dpi
    img.resolution = (300, 300)
    # Save output file
    img.save(filename='cleaned.png')
```

In the UI of inkscape in the export process we can specify this, do you know if we can do the same in python, using subprocess or a library ?

[image]

Wanted result : [image]

Unwanted result :
[image]

Comment: You say you want to convert a PNG to SVG, but the screenshot you show is for converting to PNG not from PNG. And what compression are you hoping to suppress in an SVG - they are normally just text sometimes losslessly gzipped.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my bad, i meant svg to png. I corrected my question

Comment: PNG is losslessly compressed, which is built into the file format - I don't think you could remove it if you wanted.  And since it's lossless the only difference you'll see is the file size.

Comment: For the antialias question you could try using your favorite search engine like I did:  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/32058/77997

Comment: @MarkRansom this is exactly what i've shown in the screenshot. This feature is available in the UI of Inkscape but doesn't seem like there is an option in command line

Comment: Yep, doesn't look like there's an option for that. https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/inkscape-application.cpp#L758-774

Comment: That said, _adding_ the feature wouldn't seem to be impossible; add it there, and in https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/io/file-export-cmd.cpp#L775 you'd pass in the `antialiasing` flag...

Comment: Welp, here goes: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/merge_requests/5192

Comment: thank you a lot, i've seen someone also did a merge request for this : 
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/merge_requests/5167

Comment: Nice, hope either of the MRs gets accepted!

Comment: Oh, btw, as a non-perfect workaround: you could ask Inkscape to render your image at e.g. 4x the resolution you want, and then downscale it with e.g. PIL with the `NEAREST` strategy, effectively un-antialiasing things.

Comment: @AKX that workaround is not perfect, you'll still get some antialias shades in the result rather than pure colors.  But it will definitely give you that choppy antialias aesthetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CSS property `shape-rendering:crispEdges` to suppress antialiasing. Normally, this would include changing the source SVG files. But for your scenario, you can avoid it.

#### librsvg

If you are able to use [librsvg](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg) or the commandline version [`rsvg-convert`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/rsvg-convert.1.en) for the PNG conversion. Since [v2.48](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/-/issues/379), it has the ability to load an external style sheet from the command line:

```
rsvg-convert -i layer1 -d 300 -p 300 -s crisp.css -o cleaned.png cleaned.svg
```

`crisp.css` could be defined like this:

```
:root {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

There also seem to exist Python bindings for the librsvg library, but I wasn't able to confirm they work with current versions.

#### resvg

A second library to try would be [resvg](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg). I haven't much experience yet with its quality, but at least it boasts about the feature support. Anyway, there the shape-rendering hint can be set as a command line parameter:

```
rendersvg --export-id=layer1 --dpi=300 --shape-rendering=crispEdges cleaned.svg cleaned.png
```

The Debian package I used has only v0.8.0 (latest release is 0.29), but for me it worked anyway. See [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/resvg) for more choices; Fedora for example is at v0.19, FreeBSD even has v0.28.

Comment: Did you verify that this works with `rsvg-convert` to actually suppress antialiasing?

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't affect the png export, this only affect the preview of the svg in browsers. The export still has antialiasing

Comment: Yes, for me the above command line definitively works with v2.50.3 on Linux Debian Mint Elsie. Also, all the used CSS is documented as [supported](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/librsvg/devel-docs/features.html).

Comment: [Quote](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/-/issues/379#note_1122330): "The external CSS is loaded as for the User origin; the styles declared in the SVG document have the Author origin." This means to override styles or presentation attributes set within the SVG itself they need to have a higher specificity.

Comment: Not the best render result but it works fine for my purpose, I used resvg. Thank you for your time !